# how can i export pug file with ignored extend?

Tags: gulp, pug, codeigniter-3

I'm using pug to build a static site with some layout and module(performed by `include`).
And I implement pages by `extends` method, like this:

### _layout.pug

```
html
  head
    block styles
  body
    block content
```

### page1.pug

```
extends _layout.pug
block styles
  link(href='some.css', rel='stylesheet')
block content
  h1 some content
```

And I wanna build a special version for code-igniter 3(for my teammate), without any layout codes.

I think that I have 3 options, but i don't know how to do.
1. auto replace layout file by some gulp task, I think this is a flexible method,
but I don't know how to do that.
2. using some function to ignore extends by `gulp-pug`, but I think it's impossible.
3. is there some gulp plugin can converse to CI's template(but i don't wanna use pug as template engine)

Thanks for your help!

---

## Solution:

Thanks to Gibin Ealias.

With `gulp-pug`, I can passing a parameter called `data`, here is sample:

```
gulp.task('pug-with-parameter', () => {
  gulp
    .src('[^_]*.pug')
    .pipe(
      pug({
        pretty: true,
        data: {
          testValue: 'go'
        }
      })
    )
    .on('error', handleError)
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/'));
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can use the pug `if` or `unless` condition to specify whether to render all the extends or not.

```
if renderExtends
  extends _layout.pug
```

And pass the JSON as,

`{"renderExtends": true}`

More references here : http://naltatis.github.io/jade-syntax-docs/#if

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks, can i pass the JSON as gulp-pug's parameter?

Comment: Yes, refer these answers - https://stackoverflow.com/a/38761447/7527037 - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28538918/pass-parameter-to-gulp-task